# How does 'enduring cry' calculate the number of charges?

Tags: path-of-exile

I'm using an "[enduring cry](http://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Enduring_Cry)" gem, which is described as:

> x Endurance Charges granted per one hundred nearby enemies

There will always be a minimum of 1 if there is an enemy nearby, but I'm not really clear on what is considered 'nearby', and, to behonest, even what is considered to be a hundred.

On several ocasions i've seen it produce 3 (my current character max) charges, but there weren't a 100 enemys around me, that would be a bit busy I guess. Maybe on the map? But it does seem to only work if they are actually nearby (in an empty room it doens't even produce the 1).

So it seems to me that either nearby isn't too close (which seems dubious, as per the empty room check), so maybe "100" is defined different. Total enemy character level maybe (just guessing, don't think so as it would've been easy to describe, wouldn't it?)

So why/on what count does my enduring cry gem produce 3 charges on regular basis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'nearby' refers to the range of the skill, use the visual animation of the skill as an estimate of the range. This range can be increased through 'increased AoE' passives and support gems (as well as quality% on the enduring cry gem, which gives increased AoE).

"x Endurance Charges granted per one hundred nearby enemies"

With this, for example, if x = 20, then you gain 20 charges for every 100 enemies, or ... in more readable terms, you can 1 charge for every 5 enemies.
This is also rounded up, so if you cast it on 5 enemies you get 1 charge, if you cast on 10 you get 2 charges, if you cast it on 6 you get 2 charges, if you cast it on 11 you get 3 charges. You do not have to have 100 enemies near you in order for it to work at all, and of course, when the gem levels up you need less and less enemies to get more charges (since x increases).

Comment: Thanks, sounds clear enough. Strange it is defined by 'per 100', but this would give them more fine-grained settings I suppose.

Comment: Yeah, it's mainly there instead of them saying '1 charge per 6.778 monsters' or something like that. It is quite confusing though.